# Beginner woes: Learning how to create an RCP in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-gef

I'm trying to visualise a binary tree which I wrote. In order to do so, I have been attempting to use Eclipse's GEF (Graphical Editing Framework), and followed steps found here:

http://www.programcreek.com/2011/03/eclipse-tutorial-for-a-simple-desktop-application/

However, I keep getting stuck at this page:

[image]

Can anyone offer some help here?

Comment: Something strange is wrong here. I can't get this page to behave like this at all, there should always be an error message displayed when next + finish are disabled.

Comment: ;_; really? maybe I installed something strange

Comment: I know there are some Eclipse dialogs with this kind of bug. Did you try to click on checkbox and radio buttons even if they seem to be already set?

Comment: @MathieuGarcia yup, I tried those, too (they worked). Had no idea what was going on at all, eventually I uninstalled every single thing I had installed to Eclipse (RCP, plug-in development, GEF etc. etc.) and did my visualisation by another method, so this is not an urgent issue now, but I do hope to still figure out why someday...